# MySQL DISTINCT shows multiples results

Tags: mysql

i am trying to get the unique MAC addresses in the last 10 minutes but for some reason in the outcome some results are trice, or even more often.

nID is a unique number 1, 2, 3 etc.

nLocationID is just a auto increment number like 1, 2, 3 etc.

sMAC is a table and looks like:

b8:76:3f:76:db:b3

sTimeScanned is also a table with content like:

2018-02-14 14:55:45.145049

Here is the query i am using.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(sMAC), sTimeScanned, nLocationID 
from scan_data where sTimeScanned > date_sub(now(), interval 10 minute) 
and nLocationID = 1 order by nID DESC;
```

My output for example looks like:

```
ae:b6:42:f3:ac:98   2018-02-14 15:43:20.506827  1
ae:b6:42:f3:ac:98   2018-02-14 15:43:20.475822  1
00:10:20:57:67:bc   2018-02-14 15:43:20.105565  1
00:10:20:57:67:bc   2018-02-14 15:43:20.105565  1
00:10:20:57:67:bc   2018-02-14 15:43:20.105565  1
```

Does anybody know why thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: DISTINCT operates on the whole row, not a specific field. Your rows are different due to the different timestamps. Think about it - if it worked the way you expected, which of the (potentially) many timestamps associated with the MAC address would you be expecting it to output on a single row? It wouldn't make any sense. I guess you probably just want to exclude the sTimeScanned field from the output

Comment: You'll need to switch to a GROUP BY for proper aggregation. You'll also need to specify which `stimescanned` you want for each distinct `smac`. Something like `SELECT sMAC, max(sTimeScanned), nLocationID FROM scan_data where sTimeScanned > date_sub(now(), interval 10 minute) 
and nLocationID = 1 GROUP BY sMAC, nLocationID ORDER BY nID DESC`

Answer (score 0):

You want a result set with just one row per distinct value of `sMac`. That requires a `GROUP BY` function. You probaby want

```
              SELECT sMAC, MAX(sTimeScanned) sTimeScanned
                FROM scan_data
                where sTimeScanned > date_sub(now(), interval 10 minute)
                  and nLocationID = 1 
                GROUP BY sMac
```

If you want other details from your `scan_data` table for the particular scan time, you'll need a nested query to retrieve them. It uses the above query to find the appropriate scan time for each sMac, then uses JOIN to pull the details from your original table.

```
SELECT a.sMac, a.sTimeScanned, a.nLocationID
  FROM scan_data a
  JOIN (
              SELECT sMAC, MAX(sTimeScanned) sTimeScanned
                FROM scan_data
                where sTimeScanned > date_sub(now(), interval 10 minute)
                  and nLocationID = 1 
                GROUP BY sMac 
       ) b ON a.sMac = b.sMac AND a.sTimeScanned = b.sTimeScanned 
 ORDER BY a.nID
```